# Dynamically change vector style in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using the `ol.interaction.Draw` method to draw a polygon on a map.

I don't want the user to be able to draw a polygon that is too big, or that intersects itself, so when either of those conditions are met (which I have already written code to determine), I want the lines of my polygon to change from the default blue color to red so that the user knows their polygon is not acceptable.

I know how to set the style originally for the Draw functionality but can't figure out getting the style to dynamically change **on the fly**, while the user is still drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `style` argument of [ol.layer.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) and also of [ol.interaction.Draw](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html) can be a `StyleFunction` which receives the feature and the current map resolution. You can check in this function if your geometry is valid and return an appropriate style.

Here an example where the color changes from green to red if the geometry has more than 2 coordinates:

```
var drawStyle = function(feature, resolution) {
    var color = 'green';
    if(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates().length > 2) {
        color = 'red';
    }
    return [new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: color,
            width: 2
        }),
        ...
    })];
};

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    ...
    style: drawStyle
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sad71377/

Comment: The problem I am having is I want this style to be changing as I am drawing the feature, so if two lines intersect, the color should change to red.  Right now, whatever style I define originally for the vector is what is used to finish out the drawing despite the fact that I change the style.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates().length > 2) {
draw.getOverlay().setStyle(

... your style...

};
}
```